# How to hide react-material-ui-carousel indicator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, indicator, react-material-ui-carousel

I want to hide the carousel's indicator only. (like `display: "none"`, not `visibility: "hidden"`)
but when I set `indicators={false}` property to Carousel tag, the whole component disappear.

The picture below is what it looks like when `indicators={true}`

[image]

I followed the documentation below, but I don't know why I get different results.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel

**[version]**

```
react-material-ui-carousel: 3.4.2
react: 18.2.0
@emotion/react: 11.11.1
@emotion/styled: 11.11.0
@mui/icons-material: 5.11.16
@mui/material: 5.13.6
```

here is my code.

```
    import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel';
    import { Paper, Button } from '@mui/material'
    
    function Carousel() {
    
      function Item(props)
      {
          return (
              <Paper>
                  <h2>{props.item.name}</h2>
                  <p>{props.item.description}</p>
    
                  <Button className="CheckButton">
                      Check it out!
                  </Button>
              </Paper>
          )
      }
    
      var items = [
        {
            name: "Random Name #1",
            description: "Probably the most random thing you have ever seen!"
        },
        {
            name: "Random Name #2",
            description: "Hello World!"
        }
      ]
    
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Carousel
            // problem here
            indicators={false}
          >
            {
              items.map( (item, i) => <Item key={i} item={item} /> )
            }
          </Carousel>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Carousel;
```